# ORA-12514: TNS: no listener, and unable to turn on /off lsnrctl

Tags: database, oracle, plsqldeveloper

I am unable to log in my database, with the message

> ORA-12514: TNS: no listener

I tried to run lsnrctl start / set log_status off, then it loads for a few minute and returns

> TNS-01153 : Failed to Process the String

I also realize that the listener.log file is quite big (4Gb), but since I am unable to clean the file, i am not sure if this is the problem)

Comment: On which OS are you running Oracle? Try checking if the Oracle Services are running. Indeed that 2nd error is strange. Have you or someone else messed around with tnsnames.ora or listener.ora? try and check the last records of that huge log to see if it can guide you to the problem in hand.

Answer (score 0):

ORA-12514: TNS: no listener 
Generally this problem is faced when the pc which has oracle database in it , is not on.
Check if there is a problem on your database PC.